# Adding a title to a legendGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2

My ggplots don't have legends of their own since my ggplots are updated iteratively. I want an overall legend anyways so I use the following code:

```
grid.arrange(
 arrangeGrob(grobs=plot,ncol=2,left=textGrob(colnames(data)[i],rot=90),
  bottom=legendGrob(labels=colnames(data [other_cors[,1]],pch=other_cors[,1],
  ncol=length(others),gp=gpar(col=other_cors[,1],cex=0.9)),
  right=legendGrob(labels=other_cors[,2],pch=15,nrow=length(others),
  gp=gpar(col=other_cors[,1],cex=0.9)),top=textGrob(paste("Associations with ",
  colnames(data)[i],sep=""),gp=gpar(fontface="bold"))
 )
)
```

One such plot is: [multiple ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBUUa.png)

[image]

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to add a title to the legend created on the right. Is there a way I can add a string above the red square and 0.83 line? Or is there a way of having two Grobs, eg textGrob and legendGrob, on the same side?

I want it to look like this: [Ideal plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh2C4.png)

[image]

Below is the code for the creation of my ggplots if necessary:

```
others = 1:NCOL(my_bones)
others = others[-i]
plot=list()
for (k in 1:2){
if (k==1){
data = my_bones
title = "Raw"
} else {
data = standard_bones
title = "Standardized"
}
for (j in others){
 if (j==min(others)){
  plot[[k]] = ggplot(data=data,mapping=aes(x=data[,others],y=data[,i]))+
    geom_point(x=data[,j],y=data[,i],col=j,shape=j,cex=3)+
    theme_test()+ labs(title=title)+
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
    xlim(range(data[,others]))+
    ylim(range(data[,i]))
 } else {
  plot[[k]] = plot[[k]]+ 
    geom_point(x=data[,j],y=data[,i],col=j,shape=j,cex=3)
 }
 model = colnames(data)
 model = paste("`",model[i],"`","~","`",model[j],"`",sep="")
 model = lm(as.formula(model),data=data)
 beta = summary(model) 
 beta = beta$coefficients 
 beta = beta[,1] 
 plot[[k]] = plot[[k]]+
   geom_abline(intercept=beta[1],slope=beta[2],col=j,cex=1)
 }
}
other_cors = cbind(others,round(cors[others,i],2))
other_cors = other_cors[order(other_cors[,2],decreasing=T),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten something similar to work by adding a legend title to each individual plot. So if you add

```
 + labs(col = "legend title",
        shape = "legend title"
        )
```

it should work. As long as you have the same label for each aesthetic you mapped in every plot, `grid.arrange()` should add a legend title

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that taking the legends from individual plots are possible. I was attempting to create a legend from scratch because I couldn't get the scale function to work the way I intended but I found a quick and dirty solution: Add the "title" as the first label and then change the first colour (if you're using colour) to match the background.